# How to update UI after removing the item in the futurebuilder's listviewbuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to update the UI after removing the item in the futurebuilder's listviewbuilder.

_myFutureBuilder() function returns the QueryResultSet from the database. So, I can build my listview with these values. But when I want to delete these items in the list, it is just renders the whole listview without removing the item in it. How can I properly implement this?

[image]

```
FutureBuilder(
                future: _myFutureBuilder(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  // print("SNAPSHOT");
                  // print(snapshot.data);
                  // print(snapshot.data.length);
                  // print("SNAPSHOT");
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return const Text('Error');
                    } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Flexible(
                              child: Container(
                                child: ListView.builder(
                                  key: UniqueKey(),
                                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    return Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Card(
                                          key: UniqueKey(),
                                          elevation: 4,
                                          child: ListTile(
                                            trailing: Icon(Icons.delete),
                                            title: Text(snapshot.data[index]["name"]),
                                            onTap: () {
                                              // trigger the are you sure popup
                                              //todo uncomment
                                              // _deleteOps(snapshot.data[index]["name"]);
                                           

                                               setState(() {
                                                  snapshot.data.removeAt(index);
                                              // });
                                            },
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    );

                                    //   ListTile(
                                    //   title:
                                    //       Text('${snapshot.data[index]["name"]}'),
                                    // );
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    } else {
                      return const Text('Empty data');
                    }
                  } else {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            SizedBox(height: 20),
                            Text(
                              "loading...",
                              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                })
```

```
  _myFutureBuilder() async {
    print("###########################");
    _listOfMuseums = await _checkSDCardDirectory();
    print("_listOfMuseums -> $_listOfMuseums");
    var _response = await DBProvider.instance.getInstalledMuseums(_listOfMuseums);
    print("_response -> $_response");
    print("###########################");

    return _response;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to a `streamBuilder` instead of Future builder, advantages:

- You can then convert the widget into a stateless widget.
- You don't have to worry about setState or rebuilding the UI manually, the stream will take care of it.

Doing it is simple, just replace future builder with streambuilder. Instead of `future:` it becomes `stream:`, and in your `_myFutureBuilder()` method, change it from `.get()` ==> `.snapshots()`.

Comment: I changed it the way you told but I don't understand the last part. (.get() ==> .snapshots().) I also add my _myFutureBuilder() method. stream: StreamBuilder(
                stream: Stream.fromFuture(_myFutureBuilder()), call it like that and now when I try to remove the item it returns me this; The following UnsupportedError was thrown while handling a gesture:
Unsupported operation: read-only

Answer (score 0):

Call an empty setState() when you want to refresh the screen:

```
setState(() {});
```